# Width changes when appending a cloned table to a div

Tags: jquery, width, internet-explorer-9, clone, css-tables

I'm trying to get a homebrewed scrolling table jQuery plugin to work in IE9.  It works in all other browsers (FF 3.6+, Safari 5, IE 8).  I'm using jQuery 1.6.1.

I'm doing something like this:

```
var topcontainer = $('<div class=\"topcontainer\"></div>')
                      .css({
                             "background-color":bgcolor,
                             "z-index":basez+1,
                             "position":"absolute", 
                             "top":parent.offset().top,    
                             "left":parent.offset().left,
                             "overflow":"hidden",
                             "height":headerheight,
                             "width":width
                      })
                      .appendTo(container);

var top = this.clone().css({"position":"absolute"});
top.appendTo(topcontainer);
```

The width of **this** - which is the original table element - is 914px.  After cloning **this**, **top** is also 914px.  Right *after* I append **top** to **topcontainer**, the width of **top** changes to 1118px.  This wouldn't be so bad if I could do something like:

```
top.width(914);
  or
top.css("width", "914px");
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  I've tried stripping out all the extra css I'm applying to **topcontainer**.  That doesn't seem to help either.  I noticed that **this** had a width attribute of 100% and I removed that... no dice.

I've been working on this for a couple days.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I boiled my code down to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var tableClone = document.getElementById("table1").cloneNode(true);     
    document.body.appendChild(tableClone);
});
```

So all I have is the table data, a jquery include and a doctype to make sure I was in standards mode.  This javascript was also causing the cloned table to be resized.  I verified that all my mark up was closed correctly.

What finally worked was removing all the white space between the opening <tr> and the first <th> tags in each row (yes, I do mean <th>) and also between the last </td> tag and closing </tr> tag.

Could this be a bug in IE9?  I'm starting to think yes.  Anyone have any alternate theories?